# How to create a simple search page to search for and return data from a single column in mysql from Django?

Tags: mysql, django

I found this tutorial http://gregbrown.co.nz/code/django-simple-search/ online that outlines exactly what I am trying to do but am not sure if this is the ideal way to do this in Django 1.7 still. Can anyone confirm this would still work of if there is an updated example of this same type of feature?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/. Its what I use for searching

Comment: thanks I will check into that but I really just want to understand how a basic search view is created and works.